# Disable volume controls in KDE / KMix Without Root Access

Tags: centos, vnc, kde, kmix

I'm using KDE on CentOS through a VNC session, and I never intend for any sound to be used in this session, it is always completely silent.

When I have the VNC client open (in Windows) and I press the volume control keys on my keyboard (to change the volume on the windows box), it displays a huge box in CentOS saying "It appears KMix is not running" and starts the KMix application on top of whatever I was doing.

I don't want the CentOS or KDE to do anything when I press my volume buttons, is there any way I can stop this autolaunching KMix behavior entirely?

I do not have root access to the CentOS session.

Ideally I would stop my VNC client from passing these keys, but I don't find any option to do so, so that might not be possible.

Software versions:

```
> cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
> kded --version
Qt: 3.3.6
KDE: 3.5.4-26.el5.centos.1 Red Hat
KDE Daemon: $Id: kded.cpp 534738 2006-04-27 18:04:45Z lunakl $
```

Comment: The key limitation of this question is that *you don't have root access*. With root access it's quite easy to do this. Without root access it is considerably harder. You also did not specify *which **exact*** VNC client you are using on Windows, so we can't provide specific advice on what options might be available client-side.

Comment: The program is Real VNC, though I didn't expect to find a solution by changing the VNC, as I've combed through the menus pretty extensively.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state which desktop environment you're using (it's possible you're using some combination and just happen to have KMix installed on the system), but here are the general instructions:

- In your CentOS session, look for a "Settings" or "Control Center" applet. If it's there, look inside of it for a "Keyboard" or "Shortcuts" link. The exact naming and steps to get to this will depend on your desktop environment and exact versions of components.
- Try to remap the multimedia keys. They may be named, e.g. `XF86AudioLowerVolume`, `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`, etc. if they don't have a friendly name assigned by the desktop environment.
- Look into `xmodmap` to create a `~/.Xmodmap` file to do what you want, as a last resort. See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) and the links at the bottom; it's fairly complicated.

Here are some complicating problems:

- Your VNC app on Windows may decide to "trap" the keystroke and not pass it on to further windows. Depending on the *exact* application and version, there may not be a way to tell it not to do that, so you *may* not be able to allow the volume control buttons to work on the host unless you minimize the VNC window (make it lose focus).
- "KDE", "CentOS", etc. are not nearly enough information to understand exactly what steps to take to resolve this. There are **enormous** differences in the under-the-hood functionality, configuration systems, etc. between different versions of CentOS and KDE. For instance, CentOS 5 and CentOS 6 are worlds apart in terms of functionality and versions of components and how things are configured. CentOS 4 is even more different. KDE 4 was a complete rewrite of KDE, so if you're still on KDE 3.x, your steps will be entirely different from someone running KDE 4. By not providing any version information whatsoever, you've vastly limited the potential usefulness of responses. It's like saying "I have a car that won't start. How can I fix it?" -- well if it's a sports car manufactured in September 2013 with all electronic ignition and steering, the troubleshooting steps will be completely different from a Ford Model T built in the early 20th century.

Comment: Thanks, sorry was not trying to be vague, did not realize there were so many version differences. I've added some version information to the original post, though not sure I know what a 'desktop environment' is, if not the OS/Window Manager.

Comment: Ok. Did you try any of my suggestions? Any results?

Comment: Didn't find any control center that helped me, was looking into xmodmap but haven't worked it out quite yet. I have this `keycode 255 = XF86AudioLowerVolume`, and when I change it to blank (`keycode 255 = `) it fixes the problem for a single press of the button, but when I press it a second time the xmodmap key 255 reverts back to the original assignment (LowerVolume). Something seems to be changing it back to the original every time I press the key, not sure what yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using realvnc, go to Prefrences->Expert and set the "SendMediaKeys" value to False. Then it will not send the media key input to vnc.